# No new line produced by >>

Tags: bash

I have the following piece of code that selects two line numbers in a file, extracts everything between these lines, replaces the new line characters with tabs and places them in an output file. I want all lines extracted within one loop to be on the same line, but lines extracted on different loops to go on a new line.

```
for ((i=1; i<=numTimePoints; i++)); do  
    # Get the starting point for line extraction. This is just an integer.
    startScan=$(($(echo "${dataStart}" | sed -n ${i}p)+1))  
    # Get the end point for line extraction. This is just an integer.          
    endScan=$(($(echo "${dataEnd}" | sed -n ${i}p)-1)) 
    # From file ${file}, take all lines between ${startScan} and ${endScan}. Replace new lines with tabs and output to file ${tmpOutputFile}    
    head -n ${endScan} ${file} | tail -n $((${endScan}-${startScan}+1)) | tr "\n" "\t" >> ${tmpOutputFile}   
done
```

This script works mostly as intended, however all new lines are appended to the previous line, rather than placed on new lines (as I thought `>>` would do). In other words, if I were to now do `cat ${tmpOutputFile} | wc` then it returns `0 12290400 181970555`. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why no new lines are produced - I thought >> would always put its output on a new line.

Comment: Any redirection, including `>>` does not have anything to do with newline creation at all -- redirection operations don't generate output themselves, newlines or otherwise; they **only** control where file descriptors (stdout, stderr, etc) are connected to.

Comment: ...by the way, `>>"$whatever"` is quite inefficient to perform over and over -- you'd be better off opening the output file *just once*, for the entire loop, instead of re-opening it every time you get to that last command.

Comment: ...then again, if we cared about efficiency, you wouldn't be running `sed` over and over to open a file, seek to a given line, and extract that line either.

Comment: `man tr`..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any redirection, including `>>`, does not have anything to do with newline creation at all -- redirection operations don't generate output themselves, newlines or otherwise; they only control where file descriptors (stdout, stderr, etc) are connected to, and it's the programs performing those writes which are responsible for contents.

Consequently, your `tr '\n' '\t'` is *entirely* preventing newlines from being added to the output file -- there's nowhere one could come from that doesn't go through that pipeline.

Consider the following instead:

```
while read -r startScan <&3 && read -r endScan <&4; do
  # generate your output
  head -n "$endScan" "$file" | tail -n $(( endScan - startScan + 1 )) | tr '\n' '\t'
  # append your newline
  printf '\n'
done 3<<<"$dataStart" 4<<<"$dataEnd" >"$tmpOutputFile"
```

Note:

- We aren't paying the cost of running `sed` to extract `startScan` and `endScan`, but rather are reading them a line at a time from herestrings created from the contents of `dataStart` and `dataEnd`
- We're redirecting to our output file **exactly once**, and reusing that file handle for the entire loop (over multiple commands -- first the pipeline, and then the `printf`)
- We're actually running a `printf` to generate that newline, rather than expecting it to be somehow implicitly created by magic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll have to go back into some of my other code and see where the "magical" new lines created by `>>` actually came from then. Also thanks for the efficiency comments; I'm rather new to Bash so this is very helpful. I'll implement and test this code and accept this as an answer once I've confirmed it works.

Comment: Generally speaking, any pipeline, command substitution, or subshell is quite expensive -- when possible, using [native string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), or [native means of consuming input line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) will be much more efficient. External tools are faster than bash builtins when you're using them for large streams of data, but the cost to start them up is substantial, so you don't want to spin up such a tool (or a pipeline of such tools!) inside a tight loop unless it's unavoidable.

Comment: ...on which point, if you're extracting multiple subsets of the same file, it'd be more efficient to get them all on one pass rather than trying to go over and over extracting different subsets; I'd probably use awk for the task if it was one I had myself, but how to do it best is arguably a quite different question.

Comment: I'll take a look at using awk - this has to run over a few thousands of very large files so efficiency is definitely important. On a different note, when I run your code it seems like the loop freezes on startup ( I added an echo before and within the loop and only the first echo executes ). $dataStart and $dataEnd each contain 1200 values. Could this cause problems with the read command?

Comment: Wouldn't cause trouble with `read`, no -- `read` only looks at one line at a time, so it doesn't care at all what the total size of the file is. On the other hand, `<<<"$dataStart"` requires writing the contents of the `dataStart` variable into a temporary file -- if it's huge, that could take a moment (but then, if it's that huge, I'd expect the `echo "$dataStart" | ...` to be similarly troubled).

Comment: By the way, you might want to get into the habit of using `set -x` for debugging (or `bash -x yourscript`). Much more useful than scattering `echo`s around everywhere.

Comment: ...frankly, I wouldn't expect this to *hang* as such unless the redirections were missing (if you didn't have the `<&3` or `<&4` for one of the `read`s, then we'd be reading from stdin, and thus hanging if no input on stdin were provided).

Comment: Ah, I see, the echo is placed inside the output file as well rather than being sent to the terminal. It works. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: (Aside: `3< <(printf '%s\n' "$dataStart") 4< <(printf '%s\n' "$dataEnd")` will avoid the temporary file usage).

Comment: Right. You might get in the habit of redirecting your debug logs to stderr -- `echo "Some status here" >&2` means that your logs don't get mixed up with your output, even if your program is part of a pipeline or such.